# Do not use layout for certain functions in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have defined some specific layout for my project in cakephp 3.But I don't need layout for certain functions.How to make it disable.Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this in your functions to remove the default layout :

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

In CakePHP version >= 3.5 it is this function:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->enableAutoLayout(false);
```